# Find the $4^{th}$ root of $-64$ without using De Moivre's theorem

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find the $4^{th}$ root of $-64$ without using De Moivre's theorem.

This has to be done without the use of De Moivre's theorem as we haven't learned it yet.

Comment: What do you know and how do you think we can progress?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:      $$z^4=-64=(2i)^6 $$